# Joint PMF of $X~$Bern$(p)$ and $Y~$Poisson$(\lambda)$, with $Z=XY$ and $X,Y$-iid.

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, poisson-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I am struggling with these questions.
Let $X∼\text{Bern⁡}(p)$ and $Y∼\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ be independent. We are interested in the random variable $Z=XY$.

(a) Find $\mathbb{E}(Z)$ and $\text{Var}⁡(Z)$.

(b) Find the PMF of $Z$.

(c) Compare $f_Z (z)$ to $f_Y (z)$ for all values of $z=0,1,2,\cdots$.

I have tried to solve (a), but I got stuck with (b),(c).

(a) $$\mathbb{E}(Z)=\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$$

$$\mathbb{E}(Z)=p\lambda
\text{Var}⁡(Z)=\text{Var}⁡(XY)=\mathbb{E}((XY)^2)-[\mathbb{E}(XY)]^2$$

so

$$\text{Var}⁡(Z)=-\mathbb{E}(X)^2\mathbb{E}(Y)^2+\mathbb{E}(X^2 )\mathbb{E}(Y^2 )$$

$$\text{Var⁡}(Z)=-(p^2\lambda^2)+p(\lambda^2+\lambda)$$

and thus

$$\text{Var⁡}(Z)=-p^2 \lambda^2+p\lambda+p \lambda^2=p\lambda(-p\lambda+1+\lambda)$$

$$\text{Var⁡}(Z)=pλ(1+λ-pλ)$$

Comment: Please format this properly. Use mathjax.

Comment: I have tried to format your math with MathJax. This was very hard to read, things were ambiguous in a few places, and there were a few things I believe were typos that I corrected. Because of that, please check that I have not messed up any of your work.$\tag*{}$Also, think about using MathJax/LaTeX for future questions (it's somewhat of a requirement on this site). Learning it is easy, and it's worth it if you're going to keep doing math.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $Z$ takes value zero we may compute by inclusion-exclusion:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z=0)&=\mathbb P(X=0)+\mathbb P(Y=0)-\mathbb P(X=0,Y=0)\\ &= 1-p+e^{-\lambda} -(1-p)e^{-\lambda}\\ &= 1-p(1-e^{-\lambda}).
\end{align}
For $k\geqslant 1$ we have
$$
\mathbb P (Z=k)=\mathbb P(X=1,Y=k) = \mathbb P(X=1)\mathbb P(Y=k) = pe^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.
$$
It follows from independence that
$$
\mathbb E[Z] = \mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y] = p\lambda.
$$
Moreover, we have
$$
\mathsf{Var}(XY) = \mathbb E[X^2Y^2] - \mathbb E[XY]^2 = \mathsf{Var}(X)\mathsf{Var}(Y) +\mathsf{Var}(X)\mathbb E[Y]^2 + \mathsf{Var}(Y)\mathbb E[X^2],
$$
and as
$$
\mathbb E[X^2] = p,\quad \mathbb E[Y^2] = \mathsf{Var}(Y) + \mathbb E[Y^2] = \lambda(1+\lambda)
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{Var}(X) = p-p^2=p(1-p),\quad \mathsf{Var}(Y) = \lambda,
$$
it follows that
$$
\mathsf{Var}(Z) = p(1-p)\lambda + p(1-p)\lambda(1-\lambda) + \lambda(1-\lambda)p.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I highly appreciate it.
But for point b), I have to find out the PMF by summing from k=1 to n, P(z=k)?
In this case, how do I compare fz(z) and fy(z)?

Comment: @MichaelGerund For $k\geqslant 1$ we have $\mathbb P(Z=k) = p\cdot\mathbb P(Y=k)$, so essentially mass is shifted proportionately to $\{Z=0\}$ (as according to the value of $p$).